# Why does Chrome read the svg circle radius from the style attribute?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, internet-explorer-11

I develop with chrome dev tools.

I just had a demo with IE11.

Well, yes my mistake for not checking with IE, and the syntax below wasn't intended (made a mistake setting properties in d3.js). But I'm hurt because my graph didn't display, and I want to understand the why I couldn't catch the error earlier...

The snippet below works in Chrome, not in IE11.

```html
<html>
<body>
<svg width="120" height="120">
<circle style="fill: rgb(60,60,60); r: 20px; " cy="30" cx="20"></circle>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current published version of the SVG specification is [1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) it states that the radius of a circle is an attribute and not a CSS property. That's what IE implements.

There is a new version of the SVG specification being worked on, [version 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/). In it, the radius of a circle (along with many other things that are currently attributes) would be CSS properties. That's what Chrome implements.

Chrome is experimenting with implementing parts of the SVG 2 specification as is Firefox. Different UAs have implemented different parts of the SVG 2 specification as they investigate SVG 2 prior to its completion to prove that it's feasible to implement it.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable, but in the SVG 2 doc you linked under styles it says: "The following SVG properties are not defined in CSS 2.1..." and there are the Geometry properties. Is there also a corresponding new CSS specification that allows this, is there a place where I can read black-on-white that geometry properties form SVG will be style properties?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way I could find out myself from the specification.

Comment: Or does it mean, that the style properties are defined in SVG 2 and thus don't need to be specified in CSS?

Comment: You're misreading it. The properties are not defined in CSS 2.1, they **are** defined here below. There's no separate CSS specification,  the CSS is defined in the SVG 2 specification document itself. What you're looking at **is** the black-on-white geometry properties from SVG that will be style properties. Your final comment above is correct.