# Are all SVG "non-presentation attributes" amenable to CSS styling?

Tags: css, svg, attributes

I am learning about SVG and came across this [MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#Presentation_attributes) which states "Note that all SVG presentation attributes can be used as CSS properties." In other words, in my stylesheet, this should work:

```
svg { color-interpolation: sRGB }
```

Note that the list of presentational attributes does not include all SVG attributes, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute) (e.g., **fx** and **fy** are not included in the Presentational Attributes list)

Based on these, I believed the following should NOT work.

Go to [this MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/ellipse) and open the codepen for this ellipse. You will see this SVG:

```
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<ellipse cx="60" cy="60" rx="50" ry="25"/>

</svg>
```

Based on the Presentational Attributes, notice none of the ellipses attributes (e.g., **rx**) are presentational. So my (incorrect) belief was the following should NOT work:

```
<ellipse cx="60" cy="60" ry="25"/> // remove inline rx attribute
```

and move this into my stylesheet:

```
ellipse { rx: 50 }
```

However, based on the codepen, this clearly DOES work, and you can even move ALL these non-presentational attributes into the stylesheet:

```
<ellipse /> // removed all "non-presentational" attributes

ellipse { cx:60; cy:60; rx:50; ry:25; } // written into the stylesheet -> this regenerates the ellipse
```

*So, unlike the MDN document suggests, is it true that all SVG attributes can be moved from inline to a CSS stylesheet?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome read the svg circle radius from the style attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485348/why-does-chrome-read-the-svg-circle-radius-from-the-style-attribute) (not nearly as well-written as yours, though)

Comment: As I understand it - all presentation and some other attributes

Comment: CSS only styles presentation attributes, so no non-presentation attributes are amenable to CSS styling. That said which attributes are presentation attributes and which are not is changing from SVG 1.1 to SVG 2.

Comment: @RobertLongson, but I can change cx/cy/rx/ry in my CSS stylesheet to alter the shape of the ellipse - these are "non-presentational" attributes aren't they?

Comment: They are attributes in SVG 1.1 and in browsers that implement that specification. They become presentation attributes that map to CSS properties in the upcoming SVG 2 specification and in browsers that implement that part of the SVG 2 specification, which at time of writing this is Chrome/Opera only.