# Attributes vs. style properties of SVG

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, safari, styled-components

I have an issue trying to make an animation represented on the pic. [image: VGwDC.png]

The checkbox is made of SVG paths and rect using styled components. Here's the code of the blue fill of it:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const BoxFill = styled.rect.attrs({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  rx: 0,
  ry: 0,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
})`
  fill: transparent;
  rx: 80%;
  ry: 80%;
  x: 50%;
  y: 50%;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: all ${transition.release}; // disappear

  ${Label}:hover > ${Input}:checked + ${Box} & {
    fill: ${({ theme: { checkbox } }) => checkbox.selectedHoverBoxBackground};
  }

  ${Input}:checked + ${Box} & {
    fill: ${({ theme: { checkbox } }) => checkbox.selectedBoxBackground};
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    rx: 0;
    ry: 0;
    x: 0;
    y: 0;
    transition: all ${transition.press}; // appear
  }

  ${Input}:checked[disabled] + ${Box} & {
    fill: ${({ theme: { checkbox } }) => checkbox.selectedDisabledBoxBackground};
  }
`;
```

So right now it works fine for Chrome, Firefox, etc. But Safari seems to take attributes first (rx, ry) and ignore them in styles, even though they are declared. As the result I get a sharp-bordered fill all the time. This stays as is in IE 11 (though animations doesn't work here, but for now I don't mind). This case is not appropriate.
If I set attributes (rx, ry) to 80% at the first place, then animation in Safari is what I expect, but in EI I get this picture. These white holes in a box.
[image: SyHsT.png]

I expect it to work like in the second Safari's case, but have trouble researching the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome read the svg circle radius from the style attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485348/why-does-chrome-read-the-svg-circle-radius-from-the-style-attribute)

Comment: Yes, the issue looks similar, and I already figured out that IE looks for rx/ry in attributes and ignores them in styles. But the question is how to fix it?